# An element of the chart with the name '0' already exists in 'SeriesCollection'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a fairly simple code that allows me to query the database to extract values ​​from two columns. My problem is that when I try to use two x's through DataBindTable the following error appears: A graph element with the name '0' Already exists in 'SeriesCollection'.

I was grateful for some help.

Why is this error occurring?

Here it is my code:

```
        string cs1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(cs1))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" USE [DB_SACC] SELECT  [Consumo_Medio_Real],[Tipo_de_Fatura]   FROM [dbo].[t_faturas]", con1);

            con1.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            var dt1 = new System.Data.DataTable();

            dt1.Load(rdr1);

            var enumerableTable1 = (dt1 as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();


            Chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable1, "Tipo_de_Fatura");




            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE [DB_SACC] SELECT [Consumo_Mes_Anterior], [N_Leituras] FROM [dbo].[t_leituras]", con);

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

                dt.Load(rdr);

                var enumerableTable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

                Chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable, "N_Leituras");


            }

        }
```

Here the code html of the chart:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="293px" OnLoad="Chart1_Load16" Width="801px">
                          <Series>
                              <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                              </asp:Series>
                          </Series>
                          <ChartAreas>
                              <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                              </asp:ChartArea>
                          </ChartAreas>
                      </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The chart component is throwing this exception.
Since there are hundreds of them on the market, you need to tell which one you are using and the data that is being returned so someone can help you.

Comment: I can see that you are re-binding the Chart1 again. It would be more helpful to see code of Chart1 class and DataBindTable method.

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves 
I can not further specify the error because I do not know what it refers to?

Comment: @Marshal told, you are rebinding the Chart1, this is probably the source of the problem.

Comment: I think both your enumerables have an element with the name '0', or both have an item at zeroth-index with the same name. That's all I can 'speculate' without code. I think rather than creating two enumerables, just [concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) them, and then DataBind to Chart. That way you would have just one element at zeroth index.

Comment: Well I deleted the data I had in the columns and continue to give the same error so it should not be the data what do you think?@Marshal @Vinicius Gonçalves

Comment: Chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable, "Consumo_Mes_Anterior");
Chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable1, "Consumo_Medio_Real");

Two binds. Try just one.

Comment: how ? they are from diferent colums@ Vinicius Gonçalves

Comment: What I can think is your chart is expecting a datatable with two columns, one Anterior and Real, instead your are just passing in a datatable with one column. Again this is just speculation. Can you tell what does XML comment says when you hover over DataBindTable method?

Comment: If you need to see source code html of chart i wiil post it !

Comment: Yes please, some code would help.

Comment: I already typed the code in the question@Marshal

Comment: I really need your help.@ViniciusGonçalves and @Marshal